# Error verifying client secret from backend for created subscription Stripe

Tags: node.js, typescript, react-native, express, stripe-payments

There is an error in confirming the client secret send from express backend to frontend which is a react native based application mobile app.

Sending the clientSecret the same way as stated above

**On Frontend react native mobile app**
When using the paymentIntentClientSecret the sheet displays a error "There was an error confirming the intent. Inspect the 'paymentIntent.lastPayment' or setupIntent.lastSetupError" properly

When using the setupIntentClientSecret there is below error
{"code": "Failed", "declineCode": null, "localizedMessage": "`secret` format does not match expected client secret formatting.", "message": "`secret` format does not match expected client secret formatting.", "stripeErrorCode": null, "type": null}

**On backend the code is **

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: stripeCustomerId,
    items: [
    {price: priceId},
    ],
    payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
    payment_settings: { save_default_payment_method: 'on_subscription' },
    metadata: {
        transactionId: transaction._id,
    },
    expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
});
const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
    {customer: stripeCustomerId},
    {apiVersion: '2023-08-16'}
);



if(!subscription.latest_invoice){
    throw new HttpException(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND,"Lastest invoice not found");
}
const invoice= subscription.latest_invoice as Stripe.Invoice;
const intent = invoice.payment_intent as Stripe.PaymentIntent;

return {subscriptionId: subscription.id,clientSecret: intent.client_secret,customer: stripeCustomerId, ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,publishableKey: envVars.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY};
```

Need how to confirm the payment for react frontend

Answer (score 0):

You error is occurring on the frontend and you're showing us the backend code exclusively.

From what you're saying, the issue sounds like it's coming from the fact that you're using `setupIntentClientSecret` on your `paymentSheet` - which is for [Setup Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=ios&ui=payment-sheet#collect-payment-details).

What you have is a Payment Intent - you want to use `paymentIntentClientSecret` instead:
[Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios&ui=payment-sheet#ios-collect-payment-details)

Worth noting that your Subscription could have a `pending_setup_intent` instead of a `latest_invoice.payment_intent`, in which case the Setup Intent flow would be the right one, but not here.

Comment: Used both one by one setupIntentClientSecret and paymentIntenClientSecret its just throws error on both.
Need to change the latest_invoice.payment_intent in subscription and then use setupIntentClientSecret?

Comment: depends... When you look at your Subscription, does it return anything in `latest_invoice.payment_intent` ? If so, it would suggest that you need to store `pending_setup_intent`, and use `setupIntentClientSecret` on frontend

Comment: Yes latest_invoice.payment_intent always has client secrete with it.

Comment: and logging it on the frontend returns it correctly ?

Comment: client secret goes from backend and then on frontend there is initPaymentSheet which has a parameter paymentIntentClientSecret there it goes 
logging in backend the client secret is always there

Comment: If you look at logs on your Stripe account, you should see precisely what Stripe is receiving, and get more info as to what the mismatch is. The error you got suggests you're either using a setupIntent secret on a paymentIntent confirm (or vice versa), or maybe aren't using a clientSecret at all. What does the Stripe log report you passing ?